# How to show leaderboard using JSON Manipulation in Discord.py Rewrite?

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I show a leaderboard using JSON Manipulation in Discord.py Rewrite?

The currency is accolades and I store them in a JSON file.
Any ideas on how to show a leadeboard of the top 10 people with the most accolades? I'm a beginner but I got the hang of JSON manipulation pretty easily. Here's my code.

```
python @bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You have {} accolades.".format(amounts[id]))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account.")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 0
        await ctx.send("You are now registered to AccoladeBot.")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account.")


@commands.has_
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    other_id = str(other.id)
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account.")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("The other party does not have an account.")
    else:
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await ctx.send("Transaction complete.")
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your json file to be like this.

```
{
  "ID_HERE": AMOUNT_HERE
}
```

Therefore, you can use something.

```py
@bot.command()
async def leadeboard(ctx):

    with open('amounts.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        # add 1 to postion to make the index start from 1
        names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> with {top_users[user]}\n'

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard")
    embed.add_field(name="Names", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) built-in function to sort your json file data.
Then, to display their position in the leaderboard, you'll have to use the [`enumerate()`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) built-in function.
Finally, I used [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) to make a pretty display of the leaderboard in your discord server.

Here's how your command would look:

```
@bot.command()
async def top10(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Top 10 server's leaderboard:", color=discord.Colour.gold())
    with open('amounts.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    sorted_data = {id: bal for id, bal in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True ,key=lambda item: item[1])}

    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data.items()):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name}", value=f"{bal} accolades", inline=False)
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

NB: If you want to mention the user, the mention should not be in the field's name. Mentions are not recognized in titles, field's name and footers